# Use a dataset as a datasource for Repeater control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm just learning ASP.Net, so I hope that you bear with me and my questions.  In my program, I have a dataset that contains Url strings that point to various images.  My question is, can I use that dataset as a datasource for a Repeater control so that the Repeater uses those Urls to display the images?

Thanks so much for any help and advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most certainly can. You will want to do the binding in the code-behind, probably in the `Load` method like this:

```
repeaterControl.DataSource = yourDataSet.Tables[0];
repeaterControl.DataBind();
```

where `0` is the index of the `DataTable` you're trying to get to.

Then you'll want to build the markup something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterControl" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image runat="server"
            ImageUrl="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TheFieldName") %>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

where `TheFieldName` is the name of the field/column in the `DataTable` that contains the URL. Now, this code may need to be debugged a little bit because I didn't build an entire project around this, but this will get you 99% of the way there, if not all of the way.

Comment: Thanks so much!  This is enough to get me going and I appreciate your help.  I will mark this as the answer as soon as the timer is up.  Again, much thanks!

Comment: @JavaRox, I'm glad I could be of assistance!